# Counterexample for a statement

Tags: solution-verification

Lets say I want to prove or disprove the statement $p \to q$. If I show that $p\to \lnot q$ for one particular case, isn't that a counterexample that shows that the statement is false?

Comment: Yes, certainly, although I would express it as $P$ and not Q.

Comment: @saulspatz  $p \to \lnot q \not\equiv (p \land \lnot q) \equiv \lnot(p \to q)$.  So the OP's "counterexample" does not necessarily *contradict* $p\to q$.  Please see my answer for further clarification.

Comment: @amWhy Yes, I know that, but what the OP has shown in "one particular case" is surely $p\wedge\lnot q$.

Comment: No, @saulspatz, the OP says if they find a case where $p \to \lnot q \equiv \lnot p \lor \lnot q \equiv \lnot (p \land q),$  is that a counterexample.  (Not necessarily, because if p is false it doesn't matter what the truth value of q is.  They did NOT say that they found a case where  $p \to q$ is false.

Comment: To yield a *contradiction* across the board, we need $\lnot (p \to q) \equiv (p \land  \lnot q) \not\equiv (p \to \lnot q),$ as the OP proposed.

Comment: So your comment/answer "yes certainly" is wrong and misleading.  See both answers below.

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not correct in general. For example, if $P$ is false, then you can prove that $P\implies \neg Q$, but you can also prove $P\implies Q$.

Maybe your question is abstracted from a problem in which this is not the case. You would need to give more details, in that case. As a general logical deduction, proving $P\implies \neg Q$, doesn't imply $\neg(P\implies Q)$.